# Javascript script not executed when included in a page through LI of a UL list

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic menu where pages are included according to this javacript code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#accueil").click(function(){
    $('#main').load('/Infocentre/accueil.php');
   });
```

`#main` is the central part of my site, where all the pages are displayed.

When I include a page (in my case a JustGage graph) this way, the javascript in the target page is not executed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event)
 {var g1 = new JustGage({
```

Nevertheless, if I launch this page directly the graph is displayed perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What errors do you have in the console?

Comment: Check if the "/Infocentre/accueil.php" code has jquery library.The jquery must execute only once

Comment: I have no error, but as stated if I directly launch the page with the JustGage it works even without Jquery being mentionnex in the script

Answer (score 0):

The DOM Loaded event fires when the HTML document has finished parsing.

When that happens the event handler you registered with `$()` fires and the click event is registered.

When the click event fires, the `load()` function is called. This makes a request for `/Infocentre/accueil.php` injects the HTML into the page and executes the JS in it.

That JS binds a DOM Loaded event handler.

It does run successfully.

The problem is that the DOM Loaded event has been and gone, so the new event handler is never triggered.

`$()` binds a function to run on DOM Loaded **or now if the event has already fired**.  Use `$()` instead of `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",`.

Comment: Sorry quentin, I'm not a javascript expert, so I don't know what Use $() instead of document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"means.

Comment: @ThierryDosseto  — You're already using `$()` in one script. Do the same thing in the other.

Comment: Sorry for being such a tool, but could you show me where to put that $() ? Here is the full script : document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event)
{
      var g1 = new JustGage({
        id: 'g1',
        max: 100,
        symbol: '%',
        decimals: 2,
        pointer: true,
        gaugeWidthScale: 0.6,
        customSectors: [{
          color: '#ff0000',
          lo: 50,
          hi: 100
        }, {
          color: '#0000ff',
          lo: 26,
          hi: 50
        }
        counter: true
      });

Comment: At the point you currently have `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",`.

Comment: Like this ? <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Infocentre/scripts/raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Infocentre/scripts/justgage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(), function(event)
{
      var g1 = new JustGage({
        id: 'g1',

Comment: The function needs to be an argument to `$()`, just like in the other script.

Comment: jQuery 1 is end of life …as is jQuery 2. Upgrade your jQuery while you are at it. https://github.com/jquery/jquery.com/issues/162

Comment: Well I'm at a loss, and I do not want to waste your time. Thank you for the help, I'll manage to find another way.